# Ruby on Rails Modelling users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  (validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 })
   VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 };
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX };              
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
  has_secure_password:

  (validates :password, presence: true, length:{ minimum: 6 } )  
end
```

Someone help me to figure out where this syntax has an error

Comment: Indent this code correctly.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

In your `User` model try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation { self.email = email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model should looks like below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length:{ minimum: 6 }

  has_secure_password
end
```

Comment: thanks. But is still isn't working

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You probably also want to change this line:

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

Into this:

```
before_validation { self.email = email.downcase }
```

The way this is going to go down is:

1. Validation
2. Before save callbacks
3. Actual save

So a user will use uppercase letters in his email, then save and the validations will fail because of the use of uppercase letters.

So you want to set his email to lower case letters BEFORE the validations and not after :-)